# Chrome transforms text differently over a canvas element. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, transform

It seems that **Chrome forces hardware-accelerated transforms on text that is on top of a canvas element**.

Can anyone help me understand this behavior? Ultimately, I'd like to scale text on top of a canvas element without having the text converted to a texture.

This fiddle shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Gb6h4/1/

Here is the code:

```
// Get a reference to the canvas and its context
var $canvas = $("canvas");
var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

// Make the canvas fullscreen
var width = $(window).width(),
    height = $(window).height();
$canvas.attr({
    width: width,
    height: height
});

// In Chrome, modifying the canvas context in any way
// seems to force a hardware-accelerated transform
// on the text.
// (The text is scaled as a texture, becoming blurrier.)

// Uncomment the line below and compare the difference.
// ctx.fillStyle = "grey";

// Set up a simple zoom animation on our "Hello!" div
var $div = $(".transformed");
var scale = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    scale += 0.005;
    $div.css({
        transform: "translate(0px, 0px) scale("+scale+")"
    });
}, 16);
```

In the fiddle, by default, the text scales as expected (*i.e.*, a non-accelerated CSS transform). However, after interaction with the canvas context, the text scales differently (as it would in an accelerated transform).

Comment: If the position of the element and canvas are reversed, it also uses "non-accelerated" rendering. Being "over" (in the physical layout sense) doesn't seem directly related.

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks, both! Milche: I included your link in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a a side-effect of how CSS transforms work on composited layers in Chrome today.

An accelerated 2D context causes a RenderLayer to get its own compositing layer. Moreover, **a layer that has a composited sibling with a lower z-index also gets its own compositing layer**.

*See* http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome

*Relevant bug report*: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122083.